# How to loop through array inside of Object?

Tags: javascript

```js
const obj = {
  "urls": [{
      "url": "youtube.com",
      "category": ["react js", "javascript"]
    },
    {
      "url": "facebook.com",
      "category": ["react js", "javascript"]
    }
  ]
}

const loop = (a) => {
  for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    console.log(a[j].url);
  }
  return;
}

for (let i in obj) {
  console.log(i + " " + loop(obj[i]));
}
```

The output is:

```
"youtube.com"
"facebook.com"
"urls undefined"
```

Why does the `loop` function get executed first? It should only run inside the second loop:

```
for(let i in obj){
console.log(i + " " + loop(obj[i])  );
}
```

I want to be able to output:

```
urls : youtube.com reactjs,javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

With short code often the easiest thing to do to debug it is to just do a basic walkthrough of your code by hand to see if it's really doing what you want it to.

You'll notice that the second loop simply performs:

```
console.log("urls" + " " + loop(obj["urls"])  );
```

This will result in `loop` being called:

```
console.log(obj["urls"][0].url);
console.log(obj["urls"][1].url);
return; // returns undefined
```

Which will output:

> ```
> youtube.com
> facebook.com
> ```

Only then (after the first two logs from inside the `loop` call) will the initial `console.log` take place with the return value of `loop`:

```
console.log("urls" + " " + undefined /*loop(obj["urls"])*/  );
```

Giving your last line of output:

> ```
> urls undefined
> ```

As for *why* `loop` gets called before the `console.log("urls" + ...)`, think about it, how can `console.log` know what to output, if to output it it needs to have called `loop`? `loop` has to come first.

---

It sounds like you were trying to do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "urls": [{
      "url": "youtube.com",
      "category": ["react js", "javascript"]
    },
    {
      "url": "facebook.com",
      "category": ["react js", "javascript"]
    }
  ]
}

// Constructs a string representation of the list of categories
const loop = (a) => {
  o = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < a.category.length; j++) {
    o += "," + a.category[j];
  }
  return o.substring(1);
}

// Call loop for each url in obj
for (let i in obj.urls) {
  console.log("urls : " + obj.urls[i].url + " " + loop(obj.urls[i]));
}
```

This can be tidied up using `join` instead of your `loop` function and by using `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
const obj = {
  "urls": [{
      "url": "youtube.com",
      "category": ["react js", "javascript"]
    },
    {
      "url": "facebook.com",
      "category": ["react js", "javascript"]
    }
  ]
}

// Call loop for each url in obj
obj.urls.forEach(urlObj => {
    console.log("urls : " + urlObj.url + " " + urlObj.category.join(","));
});
```